Why are there capacitors in series in this AC/DC converter?
In a circuit with an AC/DC converter that supplies 12V and then only 11.4V because of a diode (D16), I have found capacitors in series (C33 and C38, each 100µF 35V.) That makes no sense to me since each capacitor alone can be operated at 11.4V. The same with C35 and C39, 100nF 50V. These capacitors could also be operated alone at 11.4V.
Is there an explanation why the designer connected these capacitors in series?

Edit 1
To answer the questions:
This is a monitoring device for server rooms, so the temperature range is limited, +10°C to about +30°C, servers don't normally operate at other temperatures.
50µF (because of the series connection) doesn't make sense either, this is a buffer capacitor at the output of an AC/DC converter, so the capacitor could be even larger.
The 100µF is an aluminum capacitor, not tantalum.
The board only works with 12V or 11.4V and the supplied electronics are designed for this.

Very strange. Your reasoning is correct.

All I can think of is maybe for the purposes of derating for design margin

There likely is a reason but it does not read in the schematics. So we can only guess many different reasons. It is also weird to see electrolytic caps used without leakage current balancing resistors, but given that any single cap alone can handle the full voltage may make them redundant. But if imbalance is huge, there is no protection from voltage reversal.

I can maybe throw in one of the guesses that @Justme referred to.  Maybe there's a fault condition or transient due to what the output is connected to, that can cause a higher voltage on the series caps.  Still, no balancing resistors on the electrolytics isn't good design.

are they tantalum capacitors?

What is the application? Something for aerospace or medical application may have different trade-offs than a consumer product.

Another guess, is it a 'universal' board that can also be configured (by including/removing components) to dual output, by driving the mid point of the capacitors with an active voltage divider?

It seems strange to me that there are also two series 100 nF capacitors in parallel with those 100 μF capacitors. Is it obvious that the caps are in series, or could there be a bit of a trace that goes in an unexpected direction under some component that's misled you? A photo might have helped.

This is part of the original circuit diagram. I also checked the PCB, there are no other wires.

There are circuits where components are doubled for safety and/or reliability.
For example, Dubai developed high-reliability LED lamps that need not be replaced for the life of the fixture.  Notice paralleled capacitors at 18 minutes into the video.
In medical electronics, redundant series caps for line isolation might be used in case one fails as a short-circuit. If failure is stochastic, with probability of one failing being 10-5, the probability of both failing is 10-10. In the circuit given, a shorting failure would connect V++ to ground, which might have serious consequences.
Of course, sometimes parts are bought in a few values in large quantities for low price, so if a 50 µF cap is needed, and there are many 100 µF caps on hand, it might actually be more economical to use two of the larger caps.
